# Sublime Anaconda package abusive auto_complete (remove specific trigger)

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

I am using the Anaconda package for Sublime Text. Everything is working perfectly, I love it. In truth, it works a bit too well, especially the auto_complete.

[The auto_complete being zealous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61HQS.png)

Every time I write a colon (:) after a statement needing one (def, if, for, class, ...), it shows me an auto-complete list which I cannot avoid. Each and every time, I have to write a blank and erase it to be able to use the Enter key and go to the next line.

If I write a colon where it is not needed, it will not open the auto_complete list.
If I turn off the auto_complete, it stops it from happening, but it is not ideal since I like the auto_complete in general.

I know how to add triggers for the auto_complete. Is there a way to remove a specific trigger (here the colon (:))?

Comment: To start with, I would file a bug with the project's repo on Github. This plugin is actively maintained, so it's possible a fix could be devised fairly quickly.

Comment: Oooh. Yes, great idea, thanks. I should have thought about that. I will do this right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case others have the same trouble.
I found an answer here : https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/891.

Like MattDMo said, it is a bug. The proposed temporary workaround is a post from ZitCode (see the link above for the source) :

> I have found a solution (it's working, but I think it's should be a
> temporary solution 'cause it just disabling completion when ':' is
> typed) In file listeners/completion.py (can be found by click on
> 'Preferences/Browse Packages' in Sublime Text, then open Anaconda
> folder) add lines
>
> ```
> if int(sublime.version()) > 4000:
>     if view.substr(view.sel()[0].begin() - 1) == ':':
>         return
> ```

> under 86 line `view = active_view()` in function `_complete`. The file should look like this:
>
> ```
> def _complete(self, data: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
>
>     view = active_view()
>     if int(sublime.version()) > 4000:
>         if view.substr(view.sel()[0].begin() - 1) == ':':
>             return
>     proposals = data['completions'] if data['success'] else []
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the edit MattDMo (and sorry ><).

Comment: Works a treat, this was really getting on my nerves